# INSERT в цикле WHILE

Tags: mysql

Нужно в Mysql заполнить таблицу с оценками. Пытаюсь сделать это через `while` :

```
use MyDB;

Set @a = 1001;
create procedure procedure1() 
begin
label1: while (@a<1087) do
insert into assessment values
 (@a,'Mathematic',round(rand()*(5-3))+3),
  (@a,'Mathematic',round(rand()*(5-3))+3),
   (@a,'Mathematic',round(rand()*(5-3))+3),
    (@a,'Mathematic',round(rand()*(5-3))+3),
     (@a,'Mathematic',round(rand()*(5-3))+3);  #тут подчеркивает
     set @a = @a + 1;
   END WHILE label1;   #тут подчеркивает
  END;                #тут подчеркивает
```

Постоянно выскакивают ошибки синтаксиса. Всю голову сломал. Подскажите как исправить этот `while` ?

Comment: 1. Откройте любые примеры процедур. например прямо тут через поиск слова procedure для [mysql]: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+procedure  2. Посмотрите примеры, не особо обращая внимания на то о чем вопрос. 3. Обратите внимание, что при создании процедур везде используют delimiter отличный от `;` и заканчивают процедуру именно указанным разделителем

Comment: @Mike спасибо разобрался. вся проблема была в `delimiter`. зачем нужно было его обязательно отличным от ; делать ?..

Comment: По нему MySQL определяет где собственно заканчивается одна единица компиляции. А процедура должна попасть на компиляцию цельным блоком. по умолчанию клиент отправляет на анализ блоки определяя их окончание по точке с запятой, в итоге на компиляцию попадает только часть процедуры до первой точки с запятой. Поэтому меняют DELIMITER, что бы точки с запятой могли быть восприняты как часть процедуры

Comment: @Mike познавательно!